# Quarto compilation with xelatex hanging in RStudio after update to 1.2.269

Tags: rstudio, quarto, tex-live

I'm using quarto in RStudio (windows) to compile a markdown document to pdf with xelatex. Until now I was using the quarto 1.1... version, all was working fine. Today I have updated to version 1.2.269 and now I can't compile my document, the xelatex call hangs in a 'tlmgr updating' call. It generates .tex output but the xelatex call just hangs there and never ends. However my TexLive installation is fully updated, as I have checked manually with tlmgr. Launching xelatex from TexWorks works ok and xelatex can compile this .tex file and generate the correct pdf file. Any advice about what can be wrong with quarto or xelatex call from RStudio after this quarto update? Thanks in advance